# How to serialize the current form?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I am using jQuery to serialize the form of the submit button. But when I use the code, it removes the effect of `return false` and the page refreshes. And when I remove the serialization code, it works good!

I am using this:

```
$('input[value=Save]').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/ajax_requests/update_info',
      data: $(this).form.serialize(),
      success: function (data) {

      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

I am sure I am making a mistake while using `$(this).form.serialize()` but I can't figure out and neither can I search it on Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery object doesn't have `form` property, you could get the `form` using `.prop('form')` but as the returned object is a DOM Element object, for using `serialize()` you should wrap it with jQuery, so why not:

```
$(this.form).serialize(),
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't bind to the click event of a specific button, use the `submit` event of the form itself, and then your form will be `this`.

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize()
    ...
  });
});
```

If you want to use the button to reach the form, as in your example, you'd use `$(this).closest('form').serialize()`.

Comment: Using `submit` event ensures HTML5 Form validations are checked before the form is submitted.